# Has Red Gate made any decision yet on if they will soon support GIT with Sql Source Control

Tags: sql-server, redgate

Has Red Gate made any decision yet on if they will soon support GIT with Sql Source Control.  GIT is becoming the defacto source control standard and I would hate to have to support GIT and SVN in order to use this slick RG product

Comment: Suggest you go to the Redgate website and ask them.

Comment: *"GIT is becoming the defacto source control standard"* - No.

Comment: I agree. I think Git's popularity is growing exponentially. It is just so very much better than old fashioned centralized VCSs. Ask this question on Red gate site.

Comment: The right place to request and vote for SQL Source Control SCM support is at UserVoice: http://redgate.uservoice.com/forums/39019-sql-source-control

Comment: Latest news: SQL Source Control 2.1 now has support for GIT (as well as support for any source control system with a suitable command line)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Coincidentally, there was a presentation on RedGate Source Control at the [Chicago SQL Server User Group](http://chicago.sqlpass.org/) meeting last night. The only two supported systems mentioned during that presentation were Subversion and TFS.

Comment: To let you know that the decision is currently under review and we should have a better idea of which SCMs will be supported in the coming weeks.

Comment: As we can now leverage the source control command lines, pretty much all SCMs are now supported. Please try SQL Source Control version 2.1 and find out if it works for you.